Regarding 443 port issue
I have node.js application

Client-end
Back-end.

My domain www.xyz.com is assigned to client-end on port 3000
and www.api.xyz.com is for my data base port:3001
I was getting HTTPS errors for both the client-end and back-end during the deployment phase.
I have come to a conclusion that after activating SSL, I am not getting any errors for each.
But the problem is that I can't use the 443 port for both on my nginx config file, and while using it am getting errors.
If i change one of them them then it works https but for one, not for both.
I need to activate SSL for both at the same time to run my application but i cant find a solution for it.
Can anyone please share their observations on this?
It would be grateful to solve my error.
am attaching the configuration below
​
Thanks in advance.
Assume my domain name XYZ.com
server {
    #server_name _;
    server_name xyz.com www.xyz.com;
   

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
             proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.xyz.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.xyz.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
listen 8443 ssl;   
listen [::]:8443 ssl ipv6only=on;
server_name api.xyz.com www.api.xyz.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.api.xyz.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.api.xyz.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot    

#server_name api.xyz.com www.api.xyz.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}    

}

I can't use the 443 port for both — Why? Usually you can. What error do you get?
